# bluebird.js await Promise.all(); a promise was created in a handler warning

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, babeljs, bluebird

What's the proper way to `async-await` multiple promises I wish to all start at the same time.  I'm doing `await Promise.all(...)`, but...

I'm getting an annoying warning:

```
Warning: a promise was created in a handler at (path) but was not returned from it
at new Promise (path)
at MyComponent.<anonymous> (path)
at MyComponent.componentDidMount (path)
```

```js
async componentDidMount() {
    await this.fetchAB();
}
async fetchAB() {
    const [a, b] = await Promise.all([
        new Promise(function pA(r) { return r('a') }),
        new Promise(function pB(r) { return r('b') }),
    ]);
    console.log(a, b);
}
```

overwrote promises using bluebird `3.7.2` (most recent).  babel/core `7.5.4`

I've tried *everything* to silence the warning, it's super noisy, and causes the console to load very slowly.  About to disabled it `BLUEBIRD_W_FORGOTTEN_RETURN`...

Comment: componentDidMount does not require the async wrapper

Comment: thanks, I added that in an attempt to fix the warning

Comment: Is this your real code? Can you show us how you are actually calling `new Promise`?

Comment: this is not my "real code", but I received the same warning with this^  (my actual code is making http requests with the axios lib)

Comment: What happens with `async componentDidMount() {
    return this.fetchAB();
}
async fetchAB() {
    return Promise.all([
        Promise.resolve('a'),
        Promise.resolve('b')
    ]);
}`?

Comment: How is the `componentDidMount` called, does that happen somehow in a `then` callback of some other promise? (That's probably hard to track down, other than doing `console.trace()` in there, but you can also try whether you still get the warning when you render this component as top-level into your page - it would help if we had a [mcve]).

Comment: @Roamer-1888, returning does not change result.  And @Bergi there is nothing special about how the component is called.  it happens the same if within `componentDidUpdate` or any other trigger